# Talend JVM compatibility

Tags: command-line, java, jvm

Hi everyone I'm executing a job on Talend 6.3.1 on the commandline using this command :

```
executeJob job_name -i /etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0_openjdk/bin/java -jc DEV
```

and I always get the following error.

> Error Line: 8113 Detail Message: com.jcraft cannot be resolved to a
>   type

The job is using an SFTP component that calls the jsch-0.1.53.jar, the jar is present in the job but for some reason it doesn't seem to find it the commandline log shows

> !MESSAGE 2019-10-14 17:40:29,926 INFO 
>   org.talend.commons.exception.CommonExceptionHandler  - Missing jars:
>   jsch-0.1.53.jar

The job works perfectly fine when executed on the studio or even when built then executed on the server just not on the commandline.